# Find mistake in simplifying rational expression

Tags: algebra-precalculus, radicals

Why can't I simplify the following expression?
$$\frac{-(-\frac{\sqrt2}{2})}{(-\frac{\sqrt2}{2})^2}$$
I did this:
$$\frac{-(-\frac{\sqrt2}{2})}{(-\frac{\sqrt2}{2})^2}=\frac{-1(-\frac{\sqrt2}{2})}{(-\frac{\sqrt2}{2})^2}=\frac{-1}{(-\frac{\sqrt2}{2})}=\frac{2}{\sqrt2}$$
However, the correct way to do is first raise a square and then simplify:
$$\frac{-(-\frac{\sqrt2}{2})}{(-\frac{\sqrt2}{2})^2} = \frac{-(-\frac{\sqrt2}{2})}{\frac{2}{4}}=\frac{\sqrt2}{2}\cdot\frac{4}{2}=\sqrt2$$

Comment: It's trivial to prove that $x / \sqrt x = \sqrt x$ for every $x \in \mathbb R^+$. This is what you are missing apparently.

Comment: `THE correct way to` ah, there lies your mistake. You have incorrectly assumed uniqueness of a correct sequence of steps :)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

There is nothing wrong, in the sense that both final expressions are equivalent:
$$\frac2{\sqrt2}=\frac{\sqrt2\cdot\sqrt2}{\sqrt2}=\sqrt2$$
Yet $\sqrt2$ is simpler, both in number of operations and the lack of an irrational denominator.

Answer (score 3):

You are dividing two positive numbers so the result is positive.

Upon simplification of $$ \frac{-(-\frac{\sqrt2}{2})}{(-\frac{\sqrt2}{2})^2}$$ we come up with $$ \frac {1}{ \frac {\sqrt 2}{2}} =\frac {2}{ \sqrt 2}=\sqrt 2$$